# Nested resources with json fullcalendar rails gem

Tags: jquery, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar

i'm creating an basecamp-like app, using

- rails v. 4.2.3
- postgresql v. 9.3.10
  and
- [fullcalendar rails gem](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails)

A brief introduction, user can create/join many groups, from every group user can go to events through nested resources creating thus url like user_group/:id/events.

In events table except for things like title/description etc, i added user_group_id which is automaticly added from params when user add new event, and the thing is i want to get user_group_id from the url and then in index show only records of this particular group, when generating index method i can't work with params , at first it reads params from url just fine, using

```
def index
  @events = Event.where(user_group_id: params[:user_group_id])
end
```

and calling params, shows

```
=> {"controller"=>"events", "action"=>"index", "user_group_id"=>"4"}
```

which are params i want, but on second call, which i assume starts after generating json, and sending them to  [fullcalendar rails gem](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails)

```
=> {"start"=>"2016-01-31", "end"=>"2016-03-13", "_"=>"1456169154203", "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"index", "format"=>"json"}
```

Which of course results in

```
Event Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."user_group_id" IS NULL
```

Here is my index.json.builder file

```
json.array!(@events) do |event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :description, :user_group_id, :creator_id
  json.start event.start_time
  json.end event.end_time
  json.url user_group_event_url(event.user_group_id, event.id, format: :html)
end
```

Another thing is if i just set @event variable as

```
@event = Event.all
```

or if hard coded f.e.

```
@event = Event.where(user_group_id: 4)
```

it works, but i can't get it to work with params. So, my main question is, is there a way to get the params from url and put them into that query so it will work with this gem, or is there a simpler way. Thanks

Comment: Hello @donny. I didn't get why params[:user_group_id] isn't working

Comment: @goo this is the reason i posted it here, i have no clue, they are loaded properly, and later showed as list(using @events) i created on index action, but after loading all the assets they magically dissapear, i tried saving them in before_action, sending the id of group from user_group controller, but effect was allways same, before loading assets it works perfectly, but after they are not here